# Getting values of row in table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I'm trying to get information from a table I have populated into.
I got this code :

```
> dataHtml += `<tr onclick="getRowDetails(this)" class='accordion'
> id="accordion"> onclick="newAssign(this)"><td>${course.Year}</td><td>${course.Semester}</td><td>${course.Route}</td><td>${course.CourseName}</td></tr>`;
```

and once the row is clicked this function is triggered:

```
function getRowDetails(value) {
            console.log("showing this")
            console.log(value)
        }
```

and once I click on the row i see the following information:
[image]

My question is how do I approach this if I want to show the value "Big Data" only?

thanks !!

Comment: Assuming `value` contains HTML element, than you can simply select it's child: `value.children[3]`

Comment: Thanks alot !! It's working for me , by any chance do you know how can I remove the "<td>" out of the output? (the output is <td>Big Data<td>

Comment: just like any other DOM manipulations, by using [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
      function getRowDetails(value) {
        /* for (let i = 0; i < e.children.length; i++) {
          console.log(e.children[i].textContent);
        } */
        console.log(value.children[3].textContent);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var row = $(value); 
var text = '';
for (var i = 0, col; col = row.cells[i]; i++) {
    if(col.innerHTML == 'Big Data')
        text = col.innerHTML;
          alert(text);
        }
```

the syntax may be wrong, i didn't try but i guess you can solve it like this.